# Is it possible to specify custom error log format in nginx?

Tags: nginx, log-files, formatting

I can specify custom log format for access log in nginx, but it won't work for error log. I wish I always saw time when error occur. Is it  possible?

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot change the error log format without changing the Nginx source code.

Comment: possible via a custom nginx module?

Comment: Yes. You can definitely add this via an nginx module. It might also be possible to do it via Lua now or soon the Javascript scripting they're embedding.